# choosing a c++ graph library

Tags: c++, graph, benchmarking, igraph

I'm currently looking for a c++ graph library. (I saw already all the different posts here but my requierments are totally different).

With the help of the library I will have to create a some graphs (that are isomorphic to bennes network), and apply on them the bennes  network routing algorithm (In case that you are interested , the algorithm can be [found here. However, understanding it has nothing to do with answer on my question](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/classes/573/sem/s05/presentations/Paper22.pdf).)  (what you have to know about it just for get an idea of how the code will look like is that this is a simple action that involves only creating a graph and making some queries, without any complex algorithms involved).

Now, my top-3 libraries are of course:

BGL [BGL link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)

LEMON [LEMON link](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) and

igraph [igraph link](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/).

Since I will have to work with huge graphs, I'm looking desperatly for some benchmarks. I saw a [representation](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/lemon-intro-presentation.pdf) of LEMON where they claim to be better then BGL on that aspect, but I didn't find any benchmarks that include igraph (and since igraph has much more functions that are relevant to me compared to BGL and LEMON this is a library that I would be happy to use in case that it is efficient enough).

Does anyone here knows on such benchmarks (or some top important adavantages/disadvantages that I might be missing) and can share his findings with me? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Last time I used the BGL my head imploded from lack of documentation.

Comment: Yeah I already started to suffer from that while doing my research, but I already use the boost serialization in my prject and the other libraries also doesn't seem to have a detalied documantation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: One thing that you might want to look out for is that igraph is plain C (mostly), not C++. I have started a C++ wrapper for it (see: https://github.com/ntamas/igraphpp), but it's far from being usable. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of igraph).

Comment: I think you will find this post useful: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751826/which-c-graph-library-should-i-use>.

Bye!.